# Reorder rows in a Kiba job

Tags: kiba-etl

I have a kiba job that takes a CSV file (with `Kiba::Common::Sources::CSV`), enrich its data, merge some rows (with the `ChainableAggregateDestination` destination described [here](https://www.timtilberg.com/ruby/etl/2019/09/26/kiba-tips.html)) and saves it to another CSV file (with `Kiba::Common::Destinations::CSV`).

Now, I want to sort the rows differently (based on the first column) in my destination CSV. I can't find a way to write a transform that does this. I could use `post_process` to reopen the destination CSV, sort it and rewrite it but I guess there is a cleaner way...

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort rows, a good strategy is to use an "aggregating transform", as explained in [this article](https://thibautbarrere.com/2021/05/14/how-to-sort-rows-in-kiba-etl), to store all the rows in memory (although you could do it out of memory), then at transform "close" time, sort them and re-emit them in the pipeline.

This is the most flexible design IMO.

```rb
class SortingTransform
  def initialize(config...)
    @rows = []
  end

  def process(row)
    @rows << row
    nil # do not emit rows right away
  end

  def close
    # Here: sort the rows, optionally using external
    # configuration passed at init time
    @rows.sort_by { ... }.each do |row|
      yield row
    end
  end
end
```

You could also indeed re-open the output and sort it, in a secondary ETL job, but the first solution usually has my preference if it can work for you.